# Thread makes application halt

Tags: c#, multithreading, file, callback

I'm currently trying to create a FileViewer control, and after I've added Items (Filenames with Icons, size, etc) to my ListView (Icon - Filename - Extension - Size) I also check if the file is an image (png/jpg, etc) but this I do on a different Thread.

My expectation of a thread is that it runs beside the main application, but after I've added all my files I start this thread. It checks all files in the ListView and creates thumbnails for them. If done correctly, ListView icons should appear one after one as they're loaded - but they're not. They all appear at the same time.

...and I can't do anything while the Thread is active.

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong? I've dealt with Threads before and it's always worked, I invoke the method with a Callback.

Flow of the Thread:

1. Format file key =  "C:\image.png" = "C_image_png".
2. Check if thumbnail to image exists (by checking it's key), then use it
3. Else load thumbnail with Image.FromFile().GetThumbnailImage() and add image with Key to Listview's images
4. Finally change the ImageKey of the ListView item.

All done in a thread.

```
private void GetFiles()
{
   // Load all files in directory

   Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetImageFiles));
   t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
   t.Start();

}

delegate void GetImageFilesCallback();

    private void GetImageFiles()
    {
        if (this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            if (files.InvokeRequired)
            {
                GetImageFilesCallback callback = new GetImageFilesCallback(GetImageFiles);
                this.Invoke(callback);
            }
            else
            {
                string extension = "";
                string key = "";

                foreach (string file in _files)
                {
                    extension = FileManager.GetExtension(file);
                    key = (DirectoryCurrent + file).Replace(":", "").Replace("\\", "_").Replace(".", "_");

                    foreach (string knownimages in _knownImageTypes)
                    {
                        if (extension.ToLower() == knownimages)
                        {
                            foreach (ListViewItem item in files.Items)
                            {
                                if (item.Text == file)
                                {
                                    if (files.SmallImageList != null)
                                    {
                                        if (files.SmallImageList.Images[key] == null)
                                        {
                                            files.SmallImageList.Images.Add(key, Image.FromFile(DirectoryCurrent + file).GetThumbnailImage(16, 16, null, IntPtr.Zero));
                                            files.LargeImageList.Images.Add(key, Image.FromFile(DirectoryCurrent + file).GetThumbnailImage(32, 32, null, IntPtr.Zero));
                                        }

                                        files.Items[item.Index].ImageKey = key;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                files.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your thread code is using `Invoke` to run on the UI thread?

Comment: you mean this.Invoke(callback); I've tried with files.Invoke also, files is the ListView. Where am I suppose to put it? also thread.IsBackground = true.

Comment: Nothing is done on the background thread you created, it delegates everything to the UI thread.

Comment: So, how do I solve it? I've only used Thread a couple of times before so I'm not 100% on how it works in practice.

Comment: Also, code above GetImageFiles() is part of the Control (FileViewer) Control class, so the creating of the Thread is done in a different method GetFiles().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that your thread calls is invoking itself onto the main thread, and then doing all the work in that thread, thereby blocking your UI.

You should arrange your code so that the thread code does not touch the ListView, but just loads each image, then invokes a main-thread method, passing the bitmaps so that the main thread can assign them to the ListView.

Here's a sketch of what I mean:

```
// this is your thread method
// it touches no UI elements, just loads files and passes them to the main thread
private void LoadFiles(List<string> filenames) {
   foreach (var file in filenames) {
      var key = filename.Replace(...);
      var largeBmp = Image.FromFile(...);
      var smallBmp = Image.FromFile(...);
      this.Invoke(new AddImagesDelegate(AddImages), key, largeBmp, smallBmp);
   }
}

// this executes on the main (UI) thread    
private void AddImages(string key, Bitmap large, Bitmap small) {
   // add bitmaps to listview
   files.SmallImageList.Images.Add(key, small);
   files.LargeImageList.Images.Add(key, large);
}

private delegate AddImagesDelegate(string key, Bitmap large, Bitmap small);
```

Comment: This is fine, but I also don't want to load the same image more than once.

Comment: It worked, but not with parameter. I had to call the method without arguments.

Comment: I only touch the DirectoryCurrent and _files, no UI element. Does that with the Callback method. Worked fine, but couldn't get ParameterThread to work.

Answer (score 0):

Read the following: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke. The important thing with Invoke and BeginInvoke is that they both operate on the Main thread. BeginInvoke just doesn't wait for the message to be processed before returning control. Eventually though, the work will happen on the Main thread and will block until it is complete.